# Javascript Message Script by given Dates

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a javascript that displays a message on given dates. In the current script the option of a message per day is used.

Perhaps this is a too complex script for displaying certain dates every two weeks. Can someone help me out with getting the script running?

```
var days = new Array();
var msgs = new Array();

days[0] = "13 februari 2014";
msgs[0] = "13 februari 2014";

days[1] = "27 februari 2014";
msgs[1] = "27 februari 2014";

days[2] = "6 maart 2014";
msgs[2] = "6 maart 2014";

days[3] = "20 maart 2014";
msgs[3] = "20 maart 2014";

days[4] = "3 april 2014";
msgs[4] = "3 april 2014";

days[5] = "17 april 2014";
msgs[5] = "17 april 2014";

var months = new Array("",
    "januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni",
    "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"
);

var today = new Date();
var mon = months[today.getMonth() + 1];
var day = today.getDate();
var year = today.getYear();

function dateMsg() {
    for (i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        tempdate = new Date(days[i]);
        tempmonth = months[tempdate.getMonth() + 1];
        tempday = tempdate.getDate();
        tempyear = tempdate.getYear();
        if (year == tempyear && mon == tempmonth && day == tempday)
            return (msgs[i]);
    }
    return (day + " " + mon + " " + year);
}

document.write('<b>' + dateMsg() + '</b>');
```

Comment: because this is not with syntax error? "tempyear = tempdate.getYear());"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but it still doesn't diplay the propper message.

Comment: and to show a date with 2 more weeks you only need to add the right days? http://jsfiddle.net/cpduh/

Comment: use `[]` instead of `new Array`, indent your code, remove the duplication, rename your variables, use `var`for all variables, remove parentheses from your return statements, use consistent quoting... And maybe then I'll take a look at your code. Wait....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the new date `tempdate = new Date(days[i]);` you are not creating a date object because the date constructor does not accept the names for months that you are using.

Also: try replacing all instances of `getYear()` with `getFullYear()` as `getYear()` is deprecated

Here is my example with the month february in english: http://jsfiddle.net/w7jTV/4/

However, if you are just wanting different text one day every 2 weeks there are much simpler ways to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/w7jTV/5/

Comment: @ Carasel Tnx for posting the fiddle. This would be the solution if I could receive the message blah on the 13th of february in this sample.

Comment: There is probably a better way to do what you are trying to do though - see my edit.